# Issue (rewrite?) with Symfony apps (login and "not found" page)

Tags: php, symfony, url-rewriting, apache2

I state I'm not a programmer.

I am installing several PHP applications on an Apache server following the instructions on the program website.
The result is always the same: the URL is launched, a page **/login** is searched and a single blank page appears with the error "Not Found".

All these applications have in common that they are all built with Symfony, have **domain/public** as a reference folder and immediately point to a "virtual" login folder.

There is no help from those who developed the software.

The Apache server still has a basic configuration.
This is the configuration of virtual hosts

```
<VirtualHost *: 80>
     DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/app.mydomain.tld/public_html/name-app/public"
     ServerName app.mydomain.tld
     <Directory "/var/www/html/app.mydomain.tld/public_html/name-app/public">
         allow from all
         Options None
         Require all granted
     </Directory>
     ServerAlias * .app.mydomain.tld
</VirtualHost>
```

and this is a php script that I used to test the rewrite and it was successful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bolt htaccess tester.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="//normalize-css.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/normalize.css" />
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body id="home">
<?php

#htaccess tester, version 1.0

echo "<h1>Bolt Apache <tt>.htaccess</tt> tester.</h1>";

if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'htaccess_tester.php') === false) {

    echo "<p><tt>mod_rewrite</tt> is working! You used the path <tt>" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "</tt> to request this page.</p>";

} elseif (is_readable(__DIR__.'/.htaccess') ) {

    echo "<p>The file .htaccess exists and is readable to the webserver. These are its contents: </p>\n<textarea style='width: 700px; height: 200px;'>";
    echo file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/.htaccess');
    echo "</textarea>";

} else {

    echo "<p><strong>Error:</strong> The file .htaccess does not exist or it is not readable to the webserver. <br><br>Retieve a new version of the file here, and place it in your webroot. Make sure it is readable to the webserver.</p>";
    die();

}

// echo "<h1>PHPinfo</h1>";

// echo "<p>Below you'll find the specifics of your PHP installation, for debugging purposes.</p>";

// phpinfo();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

In my opinion Symfony programs need some particular configuration of the Virtual Host in Apache, but not knowing Symfony I would not even know where to put my hands.
On the other hand, those who developed the program say they don't know Apache well, perhaps because they only used the WebServer integrated in Symfony.

Hope to find help here at least on how to diagnose the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Symphony CMS or the Symfony framework? I suggest adding links to the software in use, and to the instructions you've already tried.

Comment: Based on the 'webserver integrated in' I think we could say it's Symfony.